# How can I use TestNG with Java Play 2.4.x?

Tags: java, playframework, testng

I would like to use TestNG in my Java Play project instead of JUnit for testing (it has much more robust features). However, there doesn't appear to be any documentation on how to do this since Play seems to treat Java as a second class citizen compared to Scala. Does anyone know how to configure a Java Play project to use TestNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the following dependencies to your **build.sbt**:

   ```
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     ...
     "org.testng" % "testng" % "6.8.8",
     "de.johoop" % "sbt-testng-interface_2.10" % "3.0.0",
     "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1",
     "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.4.0-M4"
   )
   ```
2. Add the following dependencies to your **plugins.sbt** (in "project [root-build]"):

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("de.johoop" % "sbt-testng-plugin" % "3.0.2")
   ```
3. Restructure your "test" directory classes to be a part of a package structure. For example:

   ```
   test
   --- com.test.integration
   ------ IntegrationTest.java
   --- com.test.unit
   ------ UnitTest.java
   ```
4. Add a new test file (ex: ExampleIntegrationTest.java) into one of your test packages ("unit" or "integration") with a very basic test. It should extend the "TestNGSuite" class (part of the Scalatest module).

   ```
   public class ExampleIntegrationTest extends TestNGSuite {
       @Test
       public void test() {
           Assert.assertTrue(true);
       }
   }
   ```
5. In your terminal / console, navigate to your project directory and run the following command:

   ```
   activator clean compile
   ```
6. Once everything has compiled, run:

   ```
   activator test
   ```

If all goes well, you should see 1 successful test executed.